# Two WQHD external monitors

Tags: display, screen, resolution, displayport

Is it possible to run two external monitors with WQHD resolution (2560 x 1440) with a Mac mini or with a MacBook Pro via DisplayPort?

According to Apple website the Mac mini is capable of handling two external monitors with a resolution of 2560 x 1600 px. But I ask myself whether this resolution is the total maximum resolution or the maximum resolution for **each** of the two monitors. I'm running two Dell U2715H (supporting DisplayPort chaining).

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple.com's Q&A section:](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MB571LL/A/how-can-i-use-the-mac-mini-with-two-monitors/QHFA7TK7KYFHUDY9F)

> The Mac Mini has two video outputs: a mini DisplayPort and a mini DVI port. The mini DisplayPort is the same one you find on the current generation MacBook, MacBook Pros (as well as the Mac Pro) and the mini DVI is the same as the on the old black/white macbook.

and:

> For 1920 x 1080 connect mini display port to DVI or HDMI. 
>   For 2560 x 1440 connect mini display port to DisplayPort.

**All you need are the adapters to connect the monitors, the Mac Mini will be able to handle both displays.**

Comment: Sure, but my question was if I'm able to connect **two** 2560x1440-displays.

Comment: @iLLogical Yes, you'll be able to. I'll edit my answer to be more clear.